# How can I connect to MySQL via LinqPad?

Tags: mysql, linqpad

I hear you can install a MySQL plugin, but where can I get that?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Quote from the first [google hit](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,374258,375111):

> - LINQPad's MySQL driver has recently been updated so that it works with
>     MySQL databases with no password. To
>     load the new driver, click 'Add
>     Connection', 'View More Drivers' and
>     select the IQ driver again to
>     download.
> - If you're using LINQPad, you don't
>     need to first download the MySQL
>     Connector - LINQPad has everything you
>     need.

Comment: Darin, you've saved me again!  I actually LOOKED at that hit, but missed the "View more drivers" part.

Comment: @Mark Kadlec, I am glad I could help you.